# Blender used by game designers?

Tags: game-engine

I hope this question is relevant to this forum...I've had a lot of incredible help from people on this site and it's always been appreciated.  I actually just have a general question: is Blender ever used by large game companies or is it sort of like how GIMP is never mentioned for graphic design jobs but Photoshop is always a must?

I'm thinking about getting into 3d modelling professionally and I love Blender.  So I guess I'm wondering if it is necessary to have to learn more commercial, expensive programs as well?

Thanks!

Comment: No, the Blender game engine has had no major studios use it, it is nowheres at that level. I would recommend learning Unity or Unreal since they are now free to use.

Comment: I do not think this is a question for this site. Nevertheless you need to differentiate between Blender and the Blender Game Engine as these are two different things. Beside of that I suggest to ask the "large game companies" what tools and methods they use. As your question is more targeting a job there ... better ask what skills they expect from you.

Comment: On [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), searching for questions containing Blender brings up 251 questions and answers. That would be a better place to ask the question than here.

Comment: see also this quite recent interview: http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/interviews/591-interview-aidy-burrows-on-blender-in-aaa-games.html

Comment: I remember this featured on BN a few months ago http://www.blendernation.com/2014/04/23/monument-valley-a-stunning-ios-game-designed-with-blender/

Comment: @m.ardito They used Unity, and only used Blender for asset creation.

Comment: Ah thanks I didn't know about gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Blender has not been used by any big game companies to create games, and no well-known games have been created with Blender. (Unless I missed them.)

However, as an experienced game developer myself, I can tell you that many have used Blender for 3D modelling, and exporting the models into other game development tools such as Unity to create games using their 3D models.

If you're thinking of getting into game development I would recommend you join [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com), and perhaps start off with a couple of YouTube tutorials on how to use Blender and Unity (or other software) jointly.